# Why are the results of `clang-format` and `git clang-format` different

Tags: c++, clang-format

this is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  QString c;
};

struct test demo[] = {{56, 23, "hello"}, {-1, 93463, "world"}, {7, 5, "!!"}};

struct test demo1[] = {{56, 44, "hello"}, {-1, 93463, "world"}, {7, 5, "!!"}};

int sdadsajdjasd(int argc, char *skasd, int b) {
  //  int a = 1;
  //  int somelongname = 2;
  //  int ff, hh;
  //  double c = 3;

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

i install `clang-format` in ubuntu22.04(WSL2),

```
sudo apt install clang-format
```

now i use `clang-format` to format `main.cpp`,command is:

```
clang-format -style=file ./main.cpp
```

result is :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

struct test
{
  int a;
  int b;
  QString c;
};

struct test demo[]
    = { { 56, 23, "hello" }, { -1, 93463, "world" }, { 7, 5, "!!" } };

struct test demo1[]
    = { { 56, 44, "hello" }, { -1, 93463, "world" }, { 7, 5, "!!" } };

int
sdadsajdjasd (int argc, char *skasd, int b)
{
  //  int a = 1;
  //  int somelongname = 2;
  //  int ff, hh;
  //  double c = 3;

  return 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a (argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show ();
  return a.exec ();
}
```

my `.clang-format` is created by `clang-format -style=GNU -dump-config >.clang-format`,so it's GNU style.

but when i  use `git clang-format` to format again:

```
git add -u
git clang-format --style file
```

the result is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  QString c;
};

struct test demo[] = {{56, 23, "hello"}, {-1, 93463, "world"}, {7, 5, "!!"}};

struct test demo1[]
    = { { 56, 44, "hello" }, { -1, 93463, "world" }, { 7, 5, "!!" } };

int sdadsajdjasd(int argc, char *skasd, int b) {
  //  int a = 1;
  //  int somelongname = 2;
  //  int ff, hh;
  //  double c = 3;

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

why are the two results different?

`clang-format --version` is:

```
Ubuntu clang-format version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
```

i also tried `git clang-format --style=file` , `git clang-format --style GNU` ,`git clang-format --style=GNU` commands, but their results are the same, still different with result of `clang-format -style=file ./main.cpp`.

Later I found out that these few lines of commented code are the key：

```
  //  int a = 1;
  //  int somelongname = 2;
  //  int ff, hh;
  //  double c = 3;
```

If I delete them then the result of `git clang-format XXXX` be corrected.

why???????? is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git clang-format` only formats changes. `clang-format` formats the whole document.

> The script clang/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format can be used to
> format just the lines touched in git commits

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#git-integration

Comment: So stupid, I get it! Turns out it was because my modification didn't touch the obvious line, thank you!!